# Find the Volume of a solid block bounded by $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, volume

I'm wondering whether I did it correctly. I see it as a region bounded from above by cone and by a sphere. I used polar form to make it easier to calculate:
$$2 \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta \int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}dr \int_{r}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\ dz.$$

Comment: I think it would be even easier in spherical coordinates.

Comment: But is it still possible to do this in cylindrical form?

Comment: Of course. It's even possible to do it in rectangular. But it does get more difficult than it has to be.

Comment: It can't be bounded above by both.  It has to be bounded above by one and below by the other, or the reverse.  And these are 2 different solids.

Comment: The two surfaces actually divide space into **three** bounded regions (and three unbounded ones).

Comment: Do you know how to calculate areas of spherical circles?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Are you asking me or Paul?

Comment: $4 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}d\theta \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}d\psi \int_{0}^{1}\ r^2sin\psi 
 \ dr   $ will it look like this in spherical?

Comment: @roffensive I'm asking you.

Comment: If it is wrong, i guess no.

Comment: Actually i only thought about the space inside to cone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two surfaces, the double cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, divide space into two bounded regions inside the sphere: the one inside the double cone
$$V_i=2\int_{r=0}^{1}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}r^{2}\sin(\phi ) d\phi d\theta dr=\frac{4\pi-2\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}$$
and the one outside the double cone
$$V_o=\int_{r=0}^{1}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}r^{2}\sin(\phi ) d\phi d\theta dr=\frac{2\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}.$$